# Get the id of the row from database on click of a button

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I guess this should be easy for the experts here ... I am using wordpress and I am fetching images from the mysql database with below code. And I display the image and there is a button just with every image and what I want is that when that button is pressed the id of that row of database that is fetched is printed on the screen. But below code only shows the last id.

Below is my code ... I want that on each button click I get that particular row id from database and print on screen with echo

Code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 1user";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $results as $result ) {
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo "<img src='$result->path' width='150' height='150' >" . '<br><br>'.'<input type="submit" name="show" id="show" value="Upvote"></form>';    

}

if(isset($_POST['show'])){

echo "<br>".$result->path;
}
```

Comment: I hope it's fine now ... anybody out there who can help with this ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WORKFLOW: I add a class and a atribute to the image the atribute is the id of the image when the user clicks the image the jquery takes the id using the `attr()` function and finds the closest `p` with the class `id-img` and displays the id
php: replace this echo

```
echo "<img class="spimg" src='$result->path' width='150' data-id='$result->id' height='150' >" . '<br><br>'.'<input type="submit" name="show" id="show" value="Upvote"><p class='id-img'></p></form>';
```

jquery:

```
$('.spimg').on('click',function(){
   $id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $(this).next('id-img').text($id);
});
```

or if you want to use the id in a form you can use a hidden input:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 1user";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $results as $result ) {
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo "<img src='$result->path' width='150' height='150' >" . '<br><br>'.'<input type="submit" name="show" id="show" value="Upvote"><input name='id' type='hidden' value='$result->path'/><input type='submit'/></form>";    

}
```

you can fetch id with `$_POST['id'];` like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){

echo 'id of image = '.$_POST['id'];
}
```

Comment: You should explain what changes you've made. **1)** Added a data attribute holding the record `id` because of *xyz*. **2)** This jQuery code does *xyz*.

Comment: ok Thanks .... infact I guess jquery might not work like this because I want to use that fetched id in a way that data insertion operation is done in another table at the same id # or row number ... and the insert operation will also execute on button click or image click in your case

Comment: will anybody help please

Comment: @Zeeshan I don't understand your requirement. What is posted here seems adequate enough for you to adapt.

Comment: I want to use the value of id with $_POST['id'] on button click

Comment: Thanks everybody the second approach worked and it shows the exact id of the image when submit is clicked